# Error During SPE 6.2 Installation due to Wrong Path, How to Change the Path?

Tags: powershell-extensions, installation

I am trying to install `Sitecore Powershell Extension (SPE) 6.2` on my local development environment on `Sitecore XP 9.2`.

As per the official Compatibility table from below link, `SPE 6.2` is compatible with `Sitecore 9.2`.

https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix

I downloaded following package from official git repository :

[image]

When I am trying to install it through `Installation Wizard`, it is giving me following error because my laptop does not have `"E" Drive`.

[image]

So, how can I change the path ?

Log file details below :

```
ManagedPoolThread #3 2023-06-14 18:14:59 ERROR Installation failed: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'E:\install\8CC254CF58A74DCD9DDC7CA1E58178FE' is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String fullPath, String path, Object dirSecurityObj, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectoryHelper(String path, Boolean checkHost)
   at Sitecore.Install.Files.FileInstaller.Install(Boolean allowOverwrite, String path, Stream stream)
   at Sitecore.Install.Files.FileInstaller.Install(Boolean allowOverwrite, String path, PackageEntry entry)
   at Sitecore.Install.Files.FileInstaller.Put(PackageEntry entry)
   at Sitecore.Install.Framework.SinkDispatcher.Put(PackageEntry entry)
   at Sitecore.Install.Utils.EntrySorter.Flush()
   at Sitecore.Install.Zip.PackageReader.Populate(ISink`1 sink)
   at Sitecore.Install.Utils.EntrySorter.Populate(ISink`1 sink)
   at Sitecore.Install.Installer.InstallPackage(String path, Boolean registerInstallation, ISource`1 source, IProcessingContext context)
   at Sitecore.Install.Installer.InstallPackage(String path, IProcessingContext context)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Install.Dialogs.InstallPackage.InstallPackageForm.AsyncHelper.<Install>b__8_0()
   at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Install.Dialogs.InstallPackage.InstallPackageForm.AsyncHelper.CatchExceptions(ThreadStart start)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error looks the same as given in this thread.

https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/issues/944

So to solve this you need to change the app pool to run under the LocalSystem account temporarily to install the package.

Check [this](https://hub.acctivate.com/articles/change-user-account-for-application-pool) to configure app pool.

Try this and hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: it worked , thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solution of using `"Local System"` Identity instead of `"ApplicationPoolidentity"` as suggested by Sumit in answer above to install `SPE`.

[image]

Also, observed that after the installation, with either  `"Local System"` identity or `"ApplicationPoolidentity"` `SPE` GUI and functionality is working fine.

`SPE` GUI with `Local System` identity below :

[image]

`SPE` GUI with `ApplicationPoolidentity` below :

[image]